# Cómo ejecutar un UPDATE en SQL SERVER para múltiples productos usando mi SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen dia

Cuando cargo una venta en mi aplicacion de escritorio hecho con C# y SQL Server, llama un procedimiento almacenado para que actualice el stock de los productos vendidos en la base de datos.

Por ejemplo si se vendio una empanada y una gaseosa, actualiza el stock de ambos productos en su tabla correspondiente.

El problema es que con este procedimiento almacenado, solamente me esta actualizando el stock del primer producto del pedido, el resto de los productos no les actualiza el stock.

Por ejemplo, a un cliente se le vendio:

-1 empanada

-1 postre

-1 gaseosa

En la tabla correspondiente, solo actualiza el stock del primer producto, que en este caso seria empanada, pero no actualiza el stock de los restos del productos, que serian postre y gaseosa.

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
@id_comida Int,
@id_venta Int,
@cantidad Int,
@precio Decimal(6,2),
@total decimal,

@Mensaje Varchar(100) Out
As Begin
Declare @stock As Int
Set @stock=(Select stock From Comida Where id_comida in(@id_comida))
Begin
-- Insert DetalleVenta Values(@id_comida,@id_venta,@cantidad,@precio,@total)
Set @Mensaje='Registrado Correctamente.'
End
Update Comida Set stock=@stock-@cantidad Where id_comida in (@id_comida)
End
```

Como lo podría solucionar?

Comment: El sp está diseñado para actualizar de a un solo `@id_comida`, por lo cual deberías ejecutarlo por cada `@id_comida` que tengas, o bien reformular el Sp, ¿tienes una tabla dónde se guarde el "pedido" con todo lo solicitado por el cliente?

Comment: Además de lo comentado por Patricio, no necesitas la variable @stock, solo referenciar la columna stock en el update.

Comment: Otra cosa adicional a lo anterior, trata de trabajar en la identación de tus procedimientos, así como esta es difícil de entender.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias !! ya vere cual de las 2 cosas hago.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea es un procedimiento comun el que llamo, mas alla de como esta hecho asi nomas rapido, si no lo entendes siendo que es un SP basico deberias reforzar tu conocimiento en SQL. Saludos